# Database Consistency History fails in SQL Server 2017 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-express

When I run the Database Consistency History report using MSSM I get an error message:

> unable to retrieve data for this section of the report. Following
>   error occured  Msg 19050, Level 16, State 5 Trace file name
>   '/var/opt/mmsql/log/log_86866.trc\log.trc' is invalid

I re ran DBBCC CHECKDB but it did not help.

When I run

```
SELECT tracefilename = path FROM sys.traces 
WHERE is_default = 1;
```

I get the *tracefilename* returned as

```
/var/opt/mssql/log/log_87148.trc
```

And if I re-run the Database Consistency History the *tracefilename* is now

```
'/var/opt/mmsql/log/log_87148.trc\log.trc' is invalid
```

Comment: What is returned when you run this `SELECT tracefilename = path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1;`? Or you could try running the query that ssms executes manually. See [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/05/sql-server-ssms-database-consistency-history-report/)

Comment: @RandiVertongen Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: It's as if the report is looking for the wrong name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation in SSMS. This report does not properly support Linux, as the script is performing path manipulation using '\', which is the Windows path seperator.

This is a snippet of code run for that report:

```
select @curr_tracefilename = path from sys.traces where is_default = 1 ; 
set @curr_tracefilename = reverse(@curr_tracefilename); 
select @indx  = PATINDEX(''%\%'', @curr_tracefilename) ;  
set @curr_tracefilename = reverse(@curr_tracefilename); 
set @base_tracefilename = left( @curr_tracefilename,len(@curr_tracefilename) - @indx) + ''\log.trc'' ;
```

You can post product feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Comment: Thanks, I posted on User Voice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38801026-linux